# Filtering data from the extjs grid on the display values

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Currently, I'm able to filter the grid using the code 
    `new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({local: true,filters:[columns]})` as plugin. But this filters the store. And as the grid contains combo cells it maintains the stored value in store and displays it via the combo renderer.

I just want to know how can this be achieved so that the filter happens on the display values of the combo and not from the store Or can it be modified to filter from grid view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm able to accomplish this using an external search input box. But not using the grid filter plugin.

Comment: Personally tried this so much time, never done since chained stores in ext6

Comment: I guess this is a valid use case. I wonder how come no one has faced/raised such an issue.